# ASP.Net Core - no redirect on API auth error

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

In my ASP.NET Core project I got a few API-Controllers with jwt-authorization like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("[action]")]
  [Authorize(Policy = MyPolicy)]
  public JsonResult FetchAll()
  {
  }
}
```

When authorization for accessing the action FetchAll() Fails I want HttpStatusCode.Forbidden as response. Instead Mvc does a reroute to Account/Login?ReturnUrl=[...]

I tried to capture the Redirect-Events and return Forbidden/Unauthorized overriding the Cookie Events to no avail:

```
  app.UseIdentity();

  var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = TokenController.DummyKey,
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
  };
  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
  {
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
  });

  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
  {
    AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
    AutomaticChallenge = false,
    AuthenticationScheme = "BsCookie",
    CookieName = "access_token",
    TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, tokenValidationParameters),
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
      OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
      {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
          context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        else
          context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
      },

      OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
      {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)
          context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        else
          context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
      }
    },
  });
```

Both Events are never called and the Visual Studio output Shows that fetchall Fails and Account/Login will be returned instead:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6460/api/v1/Lehrer/GetAll application/json 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Bearer.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action Sam.Learning2.Controllers.LehrerController.GetAll (Sam.Learning2) in 49.7114ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 121.6106ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:6460/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fv1%2FLehrer%2FGetAll
```

I want my APIs to return 401/403 instead of redirecting to Login - how do I achieve this when above code does not work?

Comment: Don't forget, `app.UseIdentity()` also registers an Cookie Authentication middleware, which has `AutomaticChallange = true`. Are you by chance still using ASP.NET Core 1.0? I think to remember that it shouldn't be possible to have more than one middleware with `AutomaticChallange` in the newer release

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update ASP.NET Core 2.x

The authorization changed a little in ASP.NET Core 2.0. The answer below ist just valid for ASP.NET Core 1.x. For ASP.NET Core 2.0 refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43962236/455493) and this [GitHub annoucement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/232).

### ASP.NET Core 1.x

What you seems to have forgotten is that `app.UseIdentity()` also [registers the cookie middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs#L35-L40).

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Value;
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.ExternalCookie);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.TwoFactorRememberMeCookie);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.TwoFactorUserIdCookie);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie);
```

and the ASP.NET Core Identity sets the `AutomaticChallange` to `true` for cookie (`ApplicationCookie`) middleware ([see source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#creating-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder)). Hence the redirect to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl`. You will need do disable this option in Identity.

```
services.AddIdentity(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
});
```

If you **really** want have Identity's Auth (login to web page) and JWT, you'd need to register the middlewares based on the url. So i.e. `app.UseIdentity()` is only registered for non-api urls and Jwt middleware is only registered for urls starting with `/api`.

You can do that with `.MapWhen` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#creating-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder)).

```
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/api"), branch => 
{
    branch.UseIdentity();
});
```

Now `branch.UseIdentity()` will only be used, for URLs which don't start with `/api`, which usually are your MVC views where the redirect to `/Account/Login` is desired.

Comment: Ah, ok, this is a different cookie middleware? Thanks, this helped!

Comment: Nice, your answer fixed this problem, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473672/asp-net-core-angular2-and-token-based-authentication

Comment: @Sam: This announcement also may be useful http://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/210 as well as the linked issues within it

Answer (score 12):

I just use  Barry Dorrans Asp Net [Authorization Workshop](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop)

in `ConfigureServices` I just add `services.AddAuthorization();`.

and in `Configure` add this code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
            else
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

In Mvc reroute to Account/Login?ReturnUrl=[...] and in API you will get 401 or 403.

Comment: I have no idea why this works on my JWT bearer token failures, but it does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's web api stack is set up to do this out-of-the-box.  The solution is at the client end.

Add this header to the client request:

```
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Web api looks for that header.  When present it returns a 401 if the request is unauthenticated.  When the header is absent it returns the redirect to the login page.

See this https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1394#issuecomment-326445124

I think you only need the more complex code in the cookie events if you cannot modify the client.